# formdata is not working in IE 9,10,11 Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to upload file into server ,for this i am using ajax and formdata to upload in server,Everything is working fine in Chrome but not working in IE version 9,10,11.

```
 var formdata = new FormData();
 for (var i = 0; i <  fileInput.files.length ; i++) {
 formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);

           }

if( fileInput.files.length>0){
                $.ajax({
                    url:path,
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: false, // Not to set any content header
                    processData: false, // Not to process data
                    data: formdata,
                    success: function (result) {
                    },
                    error: function (err) {

                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: formData isn't supported in IE9, but should work in the others ?

Comment: Currently I am using Ie 11,but still not working..